# Не работает телеграм бот

Tags: python, telegram-bot

Писал телеграм бота, который говорит пользователю температуру в его городе, залил на гитхаб, залил на heroku, сделал Deploy, все нормально, но бот не подаёт признаков жизни, не могу найти проблему.
Заранее извиняюсь, если мой код ужасен, режет глаза, а ошибка окажется наиглупейшей, я совсем новичок :)

```
import telebot
import pyowm

tokenBot = ''
tokenOwm = ''
weather = pyowm.OWM(tokenOwm, language='ru')
bot = telebot.TeleBot(tokenBot)

@bot.message_handler(commands=['start', 'begin'])
def sayHi():
    bot.send_message("Добрый день, я бот, показывающий температуру в вашем городе, введите город")
@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def getWeather(message):
    try:
        place = weather.weather_at_place(message.text)
        find = place.get_weather()
        temperature = find.get_temperature('celsius')['temp']

        answer = 'В городе ' + message.text + 'сейчас ' + find.get_detailed_status() + '\n'
        answer += 'Температура в районе' + str(round(temperature)) + 'градусов' + '\n'

        if temperature < 10:
            answer += ('На улице холодно, лучше одеться потеплее :)')
        elif temperature < 20:
            answer += ('На улице прохладно')
        else:
            answer+= ('На улице тепло')
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, answer)
    except pyowm.exception.api_response_error.NotFoundError:
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Город не найден')
bot.polling(none_stop= True)
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Убедись, что твой бот работает на Dyno worker. Они прописываються в `Procfile`. Примерно так:

```
worker: python3 main.py
```

Потом не забудь на вкладке Resources включить новый Dyno.

Comment: Сменил в Procfile web на worker, в Resources включил новый Dyno, но бот не ожил

Comment: @FMaslina Можно скрин логов? `heroku logs --tail`

Comment: Я уже нашел проблему, накосячил с try: except :)

Comment: @FMaslina Бывает :)